# Multiple images in single TTImageView

Tags: ios, uiimage, three20

I would like to include more than one `UIImage` in my `TTPhotoView`. Any ideas for a good general strategy to accomplish this? The parent class `TTImageView` has a property for a single `UIImage`, so supporting multiple images doesn't seem straight-forward. I've tried merging multiple images using quartz, then passing the single merged images to `TTPhotoView`. The performance is slow when doing this though. I hoped there is a clean way to add multiple views to a single `TTImageView`.